# Echo without interpreting newline

Tags: makefile, escaping

I have a makefile where one of the actions requires that I write a string `\noslide` to a textfile called modeset.txt, so I'm using 'echo'. Although the **-E** flag should **disable interpretation of backslash escapes** echo processes the flag as part of the sting (see output below).

Here is a stripped down snippet from my makefile:

```
.PHONY: target all

all: target

target:
    echo -E "\noslide" > modeset.txt
clean:
    rm -f modeset.txt
```

The content of the modeset.txt file shows that echo gobbled the -E as part of the string.

```
-E 
oslide
```

In a shell however, echo -e and echo -E work as expected, so what is the makefile environment doing to cause this?

OS: Vanilla Debian 8 from official sources only.

Comment: This is because on some systems (Debian included) the default shell is `/bin/sh` which implements `echo` without support for `-E`. The workarounds are either to specify `SHELL=/bin/bash` or to use explicitly `/bin/echo` (possibly defining `ECHO=/bin/echo`)

Comment: That may work on Linux systems which all use GNU coreutils for echo, but `/bin/echo` on other systems (BSD, etc.) may behave differently as well.

Comment: @MadScientist that's right, the behavior of `/bin/echo` could vary across systems and even a specific version of GNU coreutils `/bin/echo` might change its behavior depending on the setting of the environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT`. That said, the answer to the OP's question is that there is echo, echo and echo: a shell (specified in the `SHELL` variable - defaults to `/bin/sh`) builtin if it exists or a command in the `PATH` (hopefully `/bin/echo` but this might depend on the order of directories in the `PATH` if there are other `echo` commands).

Comment: What is a good portable way of doing this? (i.e. adding/appending text to a file) My workaround was to simply change the name \noslide to \xnoslide but that may not be possible always.

Comment: @kabZX there isn't a guaranteed good portable way. As MadScientist mentioned, `printf` is a good alternative to `echo`. If you want to stick to `echo`, a reasonable approach would be to set `SHELL=/bin/bash` and use `echo -E`. Setting the `SHELL` in a makefile is usually a very good idea. Note that the default behavior regarding the expansion of control characters is controled by the shell option `xpg_echo` in bash (`shopt -s xpg_echo` forces expansion by default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` is not portable, beyond simple text.  Many different versions exist that behave differently, and even within the same system it can depend on what shell you use (i.e., the shell's builtin `echo` vs the system's `/bin/echo`).

If you want to display anything other than simple text followed by a newline, you should use `printf` not `echo`:

```
target:
         printf '\\noslide\n' > modeset.txt
```